# Do css background images not get cached by default?

Tags: css, caching, browser-cache

While tuning my web app, I noticed that certain of my images are never loading from cache, even though they're completely static:

[image]

This particular file *always* loads from the server, but it should be cached. The only thing somewhat special about the file, AFAICT, is that it's sourced via a CSS class, which specifies the file via a `background-image` style. I'm not specifying any tricky headers or anything; it's just a regular jpg file.

There's a lot online about *preventing* caching, but I can't find anything about making it work when it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have caching software on your web server? If yes is it enabled? Since some can be disabled such as UnixyVarnish what is mainly found in cPanel. Images do get cached by default. Regardless of how its displayed. And your browser should automatically cache websites you visit, unless you have disabled it.